# AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'screen_width'? How to resolve this issue?

Tags: python, pygame, settings

The issue is that, when I build this code in sublime text; it gives me an output as AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'screen_width'. which is an error. I don't know, how can I resolve this? Although I had searched for that in stack overflow, those answers don't solve this problem. Can anyone help me by going through this code and identifying how to fix this issue?
Here is my `alieninvasion.py` code:

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings

def run_game():
    #Intiialize game and create a screen object
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    #start the main loop for the game
    while True:

        #redraw the screen during each pass though the loop
        screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)

        # Watch for Keyboard  and mouse events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

    # make th emost recently drawn screen visible
    pygame.display.flip()


run_game()
```

Here is my `setting.py` code

```
class Settings():
   """A class to store all the settings for Aliean Invasion """

   def __init__(self):
       """Initialize the game settings"""
       #screen settings
       self.screen_width = 1200
       self.screen_height = 800
       self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
```

Here is the return I am getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "AlienInvasion.py", line 34, in <module>
run_game()
File "AlienInvasion.py", line 15, in run_game
(ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'screen_width'
```

I look forward to finding out what simple mistake I am unable to see.

Comment: You're trying to access a variable named `ai_settings.screen_width` in the `run_game()` function, but the name is misspelled. That said, the line `self.ai.screen_width = 1200` line in `Settings.__init__()` should be giving you a `AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'ai'`—but you're not asking about that, so I suspect the code you've posted isn't what you're running. Am I putting that nicely enough for you?

Comment: I have updated the code.`self.ai.screen_width = 1200` should actually be this `self.screen_width = 1200`  And you are correct in thinking that code was not being ran. I was trying different things and pasted the wrong snip. How can you tell that `ai_settings.screen_width` is misspelled? Also, I originally meant to ask about the Attribute error. Thank you for taking the time to look over my code.

Comment: Jay: Actually I think it should be changed to `self.ai_screen_width = 1200` so it matches the other place—although exactly what name you give it isn't terribly important as long as you use it consistently and it's a simple identifier name (i.e. one that doesn't contain an embedded `.`). I noticed the problem when first trying to run your code to reproduce the problem and got an exception which was different from what's in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your Settings class doesn’t have `screen_width`, you should use `ai.screen_width`.

Comment: I am not sure I follow you. Am I not using `ai.screen_width` ?

Comment: In your code you're using `ai_settings.screen_width` but you should use `ai_settings.ai.screen_width`.

Comment: I used your settings but I am still getting an attribute error.           
  `AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'ai'`

Answer (score 0):

This should be the correct code:

`alieninvasion.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import pygame
from setting import Settings


def run_game():
    # Initialize game and create a screen object
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    # start the main loop for the game
    while True:

        # redraw the screen during each pass though the loop
        screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)

        # Watch for Keyboard  and mouse events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        # make the most recently drawn screen visible
        pygame.display.flip()


run_game()
```

`setting.py`:

```
class Settings:
    """A class to store all the settings for Alien Invasion """

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game settings"""
        # screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
        self.ship_speed_factor = 8
```

In `alieninvasion.py` you have the wrong indent for `pygame.display.flip()`. Indent same amount of `while True` statement will cause this line unreachable. I changed it in my code for reference as well as some typos.

In most other programming languages, indentation is used only to help make the code look pretty. But in Python, it is required for indicating what block of code a statement belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

to solve the (*AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'screen_width'*) you must put in your ***class settings*** the following self.ai_screen_width = 1200 and in ***alieninvasion.py*** you place, screen = pygame.display.set_mode ((ai_settings. ai_screen_width, ai_settings.ai_screen_height))

**Note**: sorry for my English, I really don't speak it very well.